# How to add a hyperlink to the email content in WordPress?

Tags: plugin-development, email

```
    $message = sprintf(__('Dear: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('As per your request on ') . date_i18n('j F Y', time());"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('Please visit the following link to reset your email address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n";
    $message .= __('In case of any queries, you can write to us at') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $email_id_reset = '<a href="support@example.com">Email</a>';
    $message .= __('Thanks and Best Regards,') . "\r\n\r\n";
```

I want to show the message like the below mentioned.

In case of any queries, you can write to us at [e-mail](http://support@example.com).

Thanks and regards

Comment: What is working or not working? What do you mean by `in wordpress`? please provide context. btw: you need `mailto:support@example.com` as `href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function set_contenttype($content_type){
    return 'text/html';
}
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type','set_contenttype');
if ( $message && !wp_mail($user_email, $title, nl2br($message), $headers) )
```

You should set the mail content type as "text/html".

Answer (score 0):

I have included these lines before sending email. now it is working fine

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    if ( $message && !wp_mail($user_email, $title, nl2br($message), $headers) )
```